# Design for car generator object

Tags: c#, json, object, asp.net-core

I'm doing a .NET Core tutorial and I have troubles with understanding of exercise. I have a simple page that contains form used to add new car to the database. User click "Add new car" and form is loaded when he has to provide: car body style (dropdown list), color, V-max, gearbox type (dropdown list), number of doors and VIN number, then he clicks "Save" and car is added to database. It is done and works fine.

Now I have to change it a bit, just so after clicking "Add new car" dropdown with possible car types is displayed, user selects specific car type and then same form as previously is loaded, but with prefilled data based on configuration file.

Exercise is as follows:
a) create JSON config file that contains predefined settings for specific car types (it doesn't have to contain all the settings),
b) propose design for car generator object.

While I had no problems with point a), I am struggling with point b), just because... I don't understand it. Example of my config file looks like that:

```
[
 {
  "Body style": "Kombi",
  "Color": "Red",
  "V-max": 240,
  "Gearbox type": "Manual"
 },
 {
  "Body style": "Sedan",
  "Color": "Blue",
  "Number of doors": 5,
  "VIN number": "SomeVIN123"
 }
]
```

What am I supposed to do now? I understand that I have to create some class that will handle data read from JSON file in order to pass it to form, but what is up with "design for car generator object"?

Is it only that I should prepare this class? Something like this?

```
 public class CarType
 {
     public string bodyStyle { get; set; }
     public string Color { get; set; }
     public int vMax { get; set; }
     public string gearboxType { get; set; }
     public int doorsNumber { get; set; }
     public string vinNumber { get; set; }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create another class:

```
 public class CarTypeEntity
     {
        [JsonProperty("Cars")]
        public List<CarType> Cars { get; set; }
     }

public class CarType
 {
     [JsonProperty("Body style")]
     public string bodyStyle { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty("Color")]
     public string Color { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty("V-max")]
     public int vMax { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty("Gearbox type")]
     public string gearboxType { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty("Number of doors")]
     public int doorsNumber { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty("VIN number")]
     public string vinNumber { get; set; }
 }
```

and to deserealize

```
CarTypeEntity result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CarTypeEntity>(yourString);
```

Your string will be this:

```
'Cars': [
 {
  "Body style": "Kombi",
  "Color": "Red",
  "V-max": 240,
  "Gearbox type": "Manual"
 },
 {
  "Body style": "Sedan",
  "Color": "Blue",
  "Number of doors": 5,
  "VIN number": "SomeVIN123"
 }
]
```

Comment: So is my understanding of exercise "b)" correct? All I have to do is just deserialize JSON config file into class?

Comment: this will give you a list<Cars> wich contains all your settings